Generate static params for nested dynamic segments while utilizing the parent segment's parameters to fetch the necessary data
Is there a way to generate static params for a nested dynamic segment that needs the params from a parent segment to make its data fetch?
For instance
> course
  > [slug]
    > quiz
      > [id]
        > page.tsx

On page.tsx, the api call would need the slug value from the parent segment to make its api call (e.g. axios.get(/course/${slug}/)) to generate the possible params for that page
